# Table of contents unwanted line

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, xetex, overleaf

Does anyone know why this line exists in my pdf? There aren't any other commands between the \subsubsection{3.5.1} and the \subsubsection{3.5.2}, just text.

Using Xetex in overleaf.

[image]

Edit: Deleting this paragraph fixes the error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You presumably had an error message at that point? If so it is more useful to show the error than the pdf output. What happens if you delete the `.toc` file does the error go?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes sorry. I included more information. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't know the macros but try deleting the .aux and .toc files and then use `\protect\say`

Comment: \protect\say seems to fix the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

using \protect\say{} fixes the issue.